# Joining 2 tables which have the same foreign key from same table but one is a one to many

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, group-concat

I want to see the activity of a particular member in my hotel. I want to see which hotel rooms they visited. However, if they visited the same hotel rooms, I only want the most recent visit of that hotel room

```
customers
+--------+-------+-----------+
| cus_id | name  | driver_id |
+--------+-------+-----------+
|      1 | bob   |     11111 |
|      2 | james |     22222 |
|      3 | sam   |     33333 |
|      4 | billy |     44444 |
+--------+-------+-----------+


hotel_rooms (cus_id is the owner of the room)
+----------+------------+--------+
| hroom_id |    name    | cus_id |
+----------+------------+--------+
|        1 | small room |      3 |
|        2 | big room   |      1 |
+----------+------------+--------+

snapshots (when we detected the user in the room)
+-------------+----------+---------------------+
| snapshot_id | hroom_id |     date_added      |
+-------------+----------+---------------------+
|           1 |        1 | 2020-01-12 12:43:13 |
|           2 |        1 | 2020-01-13 17:23:53 |
|           3 |        2 | 2020-01-19 07:34:01 |
+-------------+----------+---------------------+

participants (who was also present in the same room at the particular time we detected the customer in the room)
+----------------+-------------+--------+
| participant_id | snapshot_id | cus_id |
+----------------+-------------+--------+
|              1 |           1 |      1 |
|              2 |           1 |      3 |
|              3 |           2 |      1 |
|              4 |           2 |      2 |
|              5 |           2 |      3 |
|              6 |           3 |      1 |
|              7 |           3 |      4 |
+----------------+-------------+--------+
```

Essentially what the participant table says is:

- `snapshot_id=1` `bob` and `sam` where in `small room`.
- `snapshot_id=2`, `bob`, `james` and `sam` where in `small room`.
- `snapshot_id=3`, `bob` and `billy` where in `big room`.

The desired result for looking up `bob`'s activity:

```
+-------------+------------+-----------------+---------------------+-------------------------+
| snapshot_id |    name    | owner_driver_id |     date_added      | participants_driver_ids |
+-------------+------------+-----------------+---------------------+-------------------------+
|           2 | small room |           33333 | 2020-01-13 17:23:53 | 11111,22222,33333       |
|           3 | big room   |           11111 | 2020-01-19 07:34:01 | 11111,44444             |
+-------------+------------+-----------------+---------------------+-------------------------+
```

I cannot figure out how to combine the `driver_id` for both the owner and participants

```
SELECT s.snapshot_id, hr.name, c.driver_id as owner_driver_id, MAX(s.date_added) as date_added, GROUP_CONCAT(p.driver_id) as participants_driver_ids
FROM hotel_rooms hr INNER JOIN
snapshots s
ON hr.hroom_id = s.hroom_id JOIN
participants p
ON s.snapshot_id = p.snapshot_id JOIN
customers c
ON hr.cus_id = c.cus_id
WHERE p.cus_id = 1
GROUP BY hr.cus_id
ORDER BY date_added
```

Comment: Replace table-type example data with CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts. Specify precise MySQL version.

Comment: Which MySQL version are you using?

Comment: @Nick Database client version: libmysql - 5.6.43

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the result you want by first finding the maximum snapshot date for each room that `bob` was in, and then joining that to the snapshots table to get the latest snapshot for each room. Then you need to join to `customers` twice, once for the room owner's name, and once to get each of the participants names:

```
SELECT s.snapshot_id, 
       hr.name, 
       c1.driver_id AS owner_driver_id,
       md.max_date AS date_added,
       GROUP_CONCAT(c2.driver_id) AS participants_driver_ids 
FROM snapshots s
JOIN (
  SELECT hr.hroom_id, MAX(date_added) AS max_date
  FROM hotel_rooms hr
  JOIN snapshots s ON s.hroom_id = hr.hroom_id
  JOIN participants p ON p.snapshot_id = s.snapshot_id
  JOIN customers c ON c.cus_id = p.cus_id
  WHERE c.name = 'bob'
  GROUP BY hr.hroom_id, hr.name
) md ON md.hroom_id = s.hroom_id AND md.max_date = s.date_added
JOIN hotel_rooms hr ON hr.hroom_id = s.hroom_id
JOIN customers c1 ON c1.cus_id = hr.cus_id
JOIN participants p ON p.snapshot_id = s.snapshot_id
JOIN customers c2 ON c2.cus_id = p.cus_id
GROUP BY s.snapshot_id, hr.name, c1.driver_id, md.max_date
ORDER BY md.max_date DESC
LIMIT 15
```

Output:

```
snapshot_id     name        owner_driver_id     date_added              participants_driver_ids
2               small room  33333               2020-01-13 17:23:53     11111,33333,22222
3               big room    11111               2020-01-19 07:34:01     44444,11111
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7698ac/19)

Comment: Is there any way where it isn't a double select statement?

Comment: @James not in MySQL 5.x. In MySQL8+ you could use window functions to do that.

Comment: Also I see you are matching on the date `md.hroom_id = s.hroom_id AND md.max_date = s.date_added`. Why do we need to do that when we only want the answer to 1 instance of `hrroom_id`

Comment: @James because more than one snapshot can match with each room, by joining on the date as well we ensure we only get data for the latest snapshot for that room.

Comment: Oh I see, also what does this do `HAVING SUM(c2.name = 'bob') >= 1`? The only information I am given to do this query is the `cus_id` is 1. Also which select statement would I be ordering by date?

Comment: That ensures that `bob` was one of the participants. `c2.name = 'bob'` will be treated as 1 (if true) in a numeric context, so summing it will give a result `>= 1` if 'bob' was in the snapshot. This is paranoia, you probably don't need it because of the `WHERE` clause in the subquery, but if it's possible that two snapshots could occur at the same time for the same room and one might not include `bob` where the other does, this will filter out the result that doesn't include `bob`.

Comment: Ordering should always be applied to the outer query, it is usually ignored in subqueries unless a `LIMIT` clause is also present.

Comment: You can assume that there are no snapshops that occur at the same time for the same room. If a limit of 15 and orber by max date is present, where do these things go? The limit 15 unique recent rooms

Comment: In that case you won't need the `HAVING` clause. Add `ORDER BY md.max_date DESC LIMIT 15` after the `GROUP BY`

Comment: Could you update the answer. Unclear wht you mean, where we would have a limit of `15`